# React Redux Firebase Authentication Won't Work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I have been learning React for a couple of months now, and I just recently decided to proceed one step further into React by learning myself Redux and the integration of Firebase. I purchased this course on Udemy, where the end result was a CRUD web app using firebase and Redux. However, I found the teacher to be rather unprecise and not very good at explaining certain patterns and why he chose specific type of code etc.

In the course it was just used Twitter and Google login from Firebase, but I want to implement email login in my website - so I tried to do this myself with not the best of luck. I was hoping that you could help me solve this problem, and also maybe tell me the science behind your answer - in an attempt to maybe understand and get a better overview on how Redux works.

Basically, I have two folders called 'reducers' and 'actions'. I understand the concept of this, but the code structure is something I can't seem to grasp. Inside reducers I have two files called 'index.js' and 'user-reducer.js'.

This is the content of index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './user-reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and this is the content of the user-reducer.js:

```
import { GET_USER } from '../actions/action-types';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USER:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And now, I'll show you the contents of the action folder. It's also two files here as well, one called 'action-types.js' and 'user-action.js'. I understand the concept of action-types, and the only code inside it is this:

```
export const GET_USER = 'GET_USER';
```

This is the code inside user-action.js:

```
import { auth } from '../Firebase';
import { GET_USER } from './action-types';

export function getUser(){
    return dispatch => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_USER,
                payload: user
            });
        });
    }
}

export function performLogin(email, password){
    console.log('clicked login');
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    return dispatch => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

export function performLogout(){
    return dispatch => auth.signOut();
}
```

The performLogin method is what I tried to create myself. The original code was simply just this:

```
export function twitterLogin() {
    return dispatch => auth.signInWithPopup(twitterProvider);
}
```

Last but not least, I will provide you with my exported consts inside Firebase.js and my login page itself. Here is the Firebase consts:

```
export const database = firebase.database();

export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

And here is the source code to my login page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Icon, Input, Button, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {performLogin} from './actions/user-action';

class AdminLogin extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.clickLogin = this.clickLogin.bind(this);
}

handleLogin(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

clickLogin(e){

    console.log('function triggers.');
    performLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password);
}

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="admin-login">
                <div className="admin-login-container">
                    <div className="container-circle">
                    <img src="img/lock-icon.png" className="logo"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1 className="title-label">Administrasjon</h1>
                    <div className="login-form">
                    <form onSubmit={this.props.performLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
                    <Input iconPosition='left' placeholder='E-postadresse' className="email-input" name="email" onChange={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Icon name='at' />
                    <input />
                    </Input>
                    <Input iconPosition='left' placeholder='Passord' type='password' className="password-input" name="password" onChange={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Icon name='lock' />
                    <input />
                    </Input>
                    <Button color='grey' className="forgot-button">Glemt passord</Button>
                    <Button color='blue' className="signin-button">Logg inn</Button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="notification-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {performLogin})(AdminLogin);
```

So my question is this: Why doesn't my performLogin function work? And also, I really can't seem to find the code both provided from my tutor, nor my own code to be very good. This is because I can't really seem to get how React/Redux can catch any type of error - nor get any response from the code. I might be too used to Swift, but shouldn't the code be something along these lines (this is just an example):

```
export function performLogin(email, password){
    return dispatch => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, error) {
    if error === null {
    //provide some kind of success messsage
    } else {
    //throw an error
    }
    }

}
```

I can't really seem to find out how I would for instance return an error if the login credentials is wrong, because I want to notify the user and display an error message if it's wrong. I just want to be able to sign in with an email and a password using Redux. Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. What exactly happens, and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: @stone I was expecting to have some kind of data in my Redux state 'user' showing in my Redux dev console, some kind of indication that something is actually happening.

Comment: Your action creator looks like it's designed for use with redux-thunk. Are you using redux-thunk? (It doesn't look like it, from your code.) It would probably help you to read the docs for redux-thunk and add it to your redux store setup. https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: @stone as a matter of fact, I do. I honestly don't know what the difference is, and my tutor did not explain it either. Could you please point me in the right direction when it comes to understanding Redux/Redux-thunk - and also error handling/use of completion blocks?

Comment: That's the sort of information that is readily available in the redux-thunk readme, which you'll find in the link I provided earlier. I believe that is the right direction in which to point you.